# How to use the same scale on the y as the x but smaller because of the size difference?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, axis

I have the following code snippet:

```js
var data = [{
  "Part": 956,
  "Pos": "P2",
  "Side": "A",
  "Number": 1,
  "PIN/PAD": "A1",
  "xdim": 0.022,
  "ydim": 0.08,
  "centrex": 1.775685039,
  "centrey": 0.1945,
  "Rotated": "TRUE"
}];
var svgContainer = d3.selectAll('#svgContainer');

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 1240 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 740 / 1.5 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
//.range([width,0]);
//.range([0, width-200]);
var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(15);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(15);

var viewer = d3.select("#svg").append('g')
  //.attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width/2) - (width/4)) + "," + 35 + ")")
  .attr('id', 'viewerSVG');



var svg = viewer.append("svg").attr('id', 'viewerPins')
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) // data is the JSON
  {
    d.Length = +d.centrey;
    d.Width = +d.centrex;
    d.xdim = +d.xdim;
    d.ydim = +d.ydim;
  });

// x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Width; })).nice();
//y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Length; })).nice();

var maxW = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.Width;
});
var maxL = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.Length;
});

x.domain([0, maxW]).nice();
y.domain([0, maxW]).nice();
//y.domain([0, maxW]).nice();



// axis

var axisMovement = 0; //skipped this for simplicity

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  // did transform w/o axisMovement thingie for simplicity
  .call(xAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("x", width - 200)
  .attr("y", -6)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Width (cm)");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Length (cm)")
```

```css
interface css .canvas {
  fill: #FEFFFE;
}
#canvasChild.canvas {
  fill: white;
}
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.textNormal {
  text-anchor: middle;
  color: steelblue;
  position: relative;
  font: 14px Calibri;
}
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}
.pad956,
.pad958 {
  opacity: 0.8;
  stroke: #000;
}
#pinDataText {
  text-anchor: middle;
  color: steelblue;
  position: relative;
  font: 14px Calibri;
}
.pad956Label,
.pad958Label {
  text-anchor: middle;
  color: steelblue;
  position: relative;
  font: 8px Calibri;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="title"></div>
  <div id="svg"></div>
</body>
```

And an alternative jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/laurieskelly/q0ubpmwj/

Both the x and the y use the same domain, but they're not to scale. This is because the height is different to the width, i know, but how do i edit the y axis to use the same proportions as the x axis but just on a smaller scale.

For example, i want the x to go from 0-1.8, but the y, to say around, 0 - 1.2. But i want the y scale to be the same as the x.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out :

```
var yAxisDomain = maxW/(width/height);

y.domain([0, yAxisDomain]).nice();
```

I needed to get the difference in scale of width and height and then divide the axis width by that to get the correct proportions :)

Updated fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/q0ubpmwj/2/

Answer (score 1):

Choose the right side and scale only to it.

```
var min_dimension = width < height ? width : height;    
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, min_dimension]);    
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([min_dimension, 0]);
```

Here, i've updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fen1kz/q0ubpmwj/1/

**Edit:** Ah, since you draw y-line from top, you should adjust only from height:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, height]);    
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
```

Comment: thanks for the input but its not really what i needed. I want the size of the axis to stay the same as my fiddle but the ticks to be in proportion. So like the one you edited was great but the axis are the same size... do you understand what i mean ? kind of hard to explain ...

Comment: thanks for the help, managed to figure it out, answer below :)